# JPA - Write a "Reverse" like Predicate (like operator applied on column instead of inparam) - Oracle DBMS

Tags: java, oracle, jpa, spring-data-jpa

I need to write a "reverse" like condition with jpa predicate over oracle DBMS.
The example query i need to build is:

```
select 
    entity.*
from
    entity
where
    upper(?) like '%'||upper(entity.column)||'%'
```

the **upper(?) like '%'||upper(entity.column)||'%'** condition work in Oracle, but i haven't found any way to express with JPA predicate.

The working code of a like predicate is like this:

```
Predicate like = cb.like(cb.upper(entity.get(Entity_.column)), "%" + inputstr.toUpperCase() + "%");
```

but i need to write a like predicate as below:

```
Predicate like = cb.like(inputstr.toUpperCase(),"%"+cb.upper(entity.get(Entity_.column))+"%");
```

I have solved the problem with a namedQuery, but this condition may not be the only to apply. If present i have to add others 2 and condition and i don't want to define 3 namedQuery.

There is a way to express a "reverse" like with a JPA predicate?

Comment: One thing which may help is to change the comparison setting to make comparisons case-insensitive by executing `ALTER SESSION SET NLS_COMP=LINGUISTIC` and `ALTER SESSION SET NLS_SORT=BINARY_CI`. This would eliminate the need for `.upper`/`.toUpperCase`. I don't know if this will fix whatever other issues you're encountering, but it might simplify things a bit. Best of luck.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I solved using instr called through locate, using 2 defined expression, to switch the operators:

```
Expression<String> tableColumnInUpper = cb.upper(entity.get(Entity_.column));
Expression<String> searchStringUpper = cb.upper(cb.literal(searchString));
predicates.add(cb.gt(cb.locate(searchStringUpper, tableColumnInUpper), 0));
```

With this code i was able to call **INSTR(upper(?),upper(entity.column)) > 0**

However, i wasn't able to find a solution to to define the expression I wanted to use, **upper(?) like '%'||upper(entity.column)||'%'**, but are equivalent, so that's okay!

Answer (score 0):

If you can change your query then the following query will work.

```
select 
    entity.*
from
    entity
where
    INSTR(upper(?),upper(entity.column)) > 0;
```

Comment: For what i know, and i searched again, there is no equivalent predicate for INSTR in JPA, so also using INSTR i have to define a named query, but if possible i need to use predicate and avoid the use of namedquery.

Comment: i found a way to call instr with switched operators. I wrote an answer with the solution.